# Limit Notation with many variable below of it

Tags: math-mode, code

what is the Limit Notation's code  with many variables below of it?

What I need is exactly what depicted in picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\[:\enspace\liminf_{\substack{\tau\searrow 0 \\w'\to w}}\Delta_\tau^2f(\bar x\mid v)(w') \]
```

should be fine, although I don't see what the colon is here for..